# Removing InfluxDB retention time without flushing old data

Tags: influxdb

I have a [retention policy](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/query_language/database_management/#retention-policy-management) on an InfluxDB database that expires data after 7 days.  I have tried deleting the policy, and found that the data (for the past 7 days) is wiped out as well.  I'd like to delete the retention policy while keeping the existing data.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your data into another RP, say `autogen` (generated by default, has infinite retention duration):

```
SELECT *
INTO "autogen"."measurement" 
FROM "7_days"."measurement"
```

And than you just drop all the data from `7_days` RP:

```
USE "database"."7_days"

DELETE 
FROM "measurement"
```

Comment: try this: `USE "database"."autogen"` and then `SELECT * FROM "measurement"`.